# Pull to reveal hidden navBar-like menu in iOS? as seen in GetPocket App

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've been driving myself mad over this one. It might be one of those things where I need to take a step back and figure out the simplest way to implement this. Can't find anything on this either. I google-fu'd the heck out of this one.

In the Pocket App when you pull down a menu reveals itself just like the searchBar does. In this instance the faux bar when you pull it past its halfway point if you release it shows springs into place. If it is release before the halfway point the bar will snap back and hide. As shown here

[image]

In my case I've been trying to replicate this with no luck. In my case I have a UITextView inside of a UIViewController view. I think I have it all wrong.

I can get it to work with a UIScrollView hidden by initiating with it offscreen and then when I press a button the UIScrollView reveals itself. The problem is that this method covers everything so I'll have to resize and relayout a bunch of views. Is this in a UITableView possibly? I want it to be a pull action though and just want to put some TextStrings/Labels in this bar.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This could be pretty good.. Interested in a way to do this if you ever find a solution !

Comment: @rdurand I was thinking of making this my first library to share. I swear I looked all over and I just kept finding Pull to Refresh. Like a million different ways to pull to refresh.

Comment: Well, let me know if you share it some day (no idea how, lol), I'd love to take a look at it !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feels like you need a UIScrollView (or UITableView) and to put the menu you want to reveal at the top (in the table view header, for example) and then get the delegate callbacks for scrolling.

```
UIScrollViewDelegate
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

You might also need to watch for some of the dragging delegate callbacks

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

You can initially hide the menu by setting the content offset to the height of the menu, then catch the delegate callbacks for scrolling and, if the scrolling has reached beyond half the size of the menu set the content offset with animation.

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I think thats where I was getting hung up on, the content offset. I should have read the UIScrollViewDelegate reference more closely.

Once I took a step back and did some chores around the house I realized that there is one disadvantage to this hidden menu. Although it is very sleek in my case where the user will be typing copious amounts of text into the UITextView scrolling all the way to the top to access this menu would not make sense. Additionally if I had it autoscroll the user would lose his/her place.
cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal correctly you don't need the scroll view.

What I would do is have an simple `UIView` containing all the stuff you need and place it outside of the visible area. This will be your pull-down view. Then add an `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the view in your `UIViewController` and use it to track the movement of your finger and update the frame of the  pull-down view accordingly. Then in this update method you simply check if the position has passed some threshold and if so you let the pull-down view snap to its final position (using animations of course).

If you are unfamiliar with the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` there is a really good tutorial here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

Comment: thank you. I may try an implementation similar to this. I still have yet found the time to implement these suggestions into my code as I have been working on other aspects of the app.